# How to shut down the S/PDIF output in my sound card?

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa

I realized that there is a red light coming out of my earphone jack. It's something like this:

[image]

I looked in the folder that Toshiba created for installing drivers , then I found out that they had installed this driver for my sound card: Realtek HD Audio Driver v6.0.1.5689_withMaxxAudio_Compal(20080908)

I'm guessing that the sound card supports Optical Audio Output. I also found out that when I mute the speakers, the light goes away. But when I unmute it, it comes back.

I don't really mind having it but it drains my battery. So, is there a Ubuntu version for my sound card driver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so I followed Tenplus1's answer and it seemed to work. But it got restored after reboots. So I did some research and found a way.

1. Open Terminal by `Ctrl + Alt + T`
2. Type in `sudo alsamixer`
3. Use the arrow keys to move around and when over S/PDIF press `M` to mute, this will turn the light OFF.
4. Hit the `Escape` key - **DO NOT CLOSE TERMINAL**
5. Type `sudo alsactl store` - This will make it persist across reboots
6. Close Terminal

Answer (score 8):

Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> keyboard shortcut and type:    `alsamixer`

Use the arrow keys to move around and when over S/PDIF press <kbd>M</kbd> to mute, this will turn the light OFF.  Hit the  <kbd>escape</kbd> key to leave or just close the terminal.

Comment: both are doing same thing.

Comment: Wait... Your method disables it temporarily.
What I mean is that when I reboot my computer, the light come backs on. Is there any way to disable it permanently?

Comment: I did not work on my Macbook Pro.

Answer (score 1):

It did not work in my case but I found a "trick" that does the job, so maybe it will be useful for someone. Just type this in terminal:

```
echo "1" > /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save
```

If it works, add it to your start-up scripts.